# Absolute value $\lvert x \rvert >-1$ (precalculus)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

How can $\lvert x \rvert >-1$ be true for all real $x$?

If $x\geq 0$: $x>-1$.

If $x<0$: $-x>-1 \iff x<1$.

So $-1<x<1$.

But if I for instance take $x=-5$ I get $\lvert -5 \rvert >-1 \iff -(-5)>-1 \iff 5>-1$. This is true but contradicts $-1<x<1$.

What is wrong here?

**Update:**

Would it be any difference if I instead had $\lvert x\rvert \geq -1$?

Comment: You're first two lines show that $x>-1$ OR $x<1$, not AND. Thus, your combination of those inequalities is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Your analysis is flawed. Your conclusion "$x>-1$" on the second line only follows under your condition that "$x\geq 0$". But the conclusion "$x<1$" on the third line only follows under your condition that "$x<0$".

These are mutually exclusive conditions -- there is no $x$ that simultaneously satisfies them both. You are combining conclusions from different assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't approach it like that.  I mean, don't consider $x \ge 0$ as one case and $x < 0$ as another case.  Breaking into two inequalities like you did is fine, but technically they are not "$x \ge 0$" and "$x < 0$".

$|x| > -1$ is really the following compound inequality:

$$x > -1 \text{ OR } x < -(-1)$$

I think you approached it with AND in mind instead of OR.

But since it's "$|x| > \ $" then it should be OR.

The first inequality just gives you $x > -1$.  The second one is $x < 1$.  So you get:

$$ x > -1 \text{ OR } x < 1$$

And together these two inequalities just mean $x$ can be any real number.

Formal side note:  OR is union: $\cup$.  AND is intersection: $\cap$.

---

An easier way to approach this specific problem:  $|x| \ge 0$ no matter what $x$ is.  And since $0 > -1$, then no matter what $x$ is, you will always have $|x| \ge 0 > -1$.  Therefore $|x| > -1$ is true for all real values of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

it is true, since for $$|x|$$ we have $$|x|\geq 0$$ and $$0>-1$$

Comment: -1: This entirely fails to address the question, which is about a proof that the OP wrote and why it is wrong.

Comment: Simple and sweet!

Answer (score 0):

These are two independent cases. A particular value of $x$ satisfies *one* of the cases, not both. Therefore combining the inequalities is incorrect.

You have "if $x<0$ then $-x > -1$" and "if $x\geq 0$ then $x > -1$" but no number satisfies both of those conditionals.

Comment: @downvoters Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

your mistake is in the logical formulation of the statement. The correct formulation is:

> $|x|>-1$ if and only if $\{x\ge 0$ **and** $x>-1\}$ **or** $\{x<0$ **and** $-x>-1\}$

If you solve correctly for the logical connectives you don't met contradictions.